# Should "play" or "plays" be used in this context?

Tags: verb-agreement

> Every fairy in my home village weeps for weeks in deep sorrow every time one of you meanies **plays** these butchered versions of Ocarina of Time.

Or:

> Every fairy in my home village weeps for weeks in deep sorrow every time one of you meanies **play** these butchered versions of Ocarina of Time.

?

It's referring to **ONE** of you meanies, so it should be "plays", but "meanies" is plural, so it should be "play"?

Comment: 'One of our aircraft are missing'? 'One of my children are playing "Bohemian Rhapsody" '?

Comment: *One of you meanies* is a singular subject; it doesn't matter that *meanies* is plural, it's just part of the singular subject phrase.

Comment: ***One of*** *[the many people who kick and scream, playing alone or together, with their compatriot clowns who make us laugh]* ***is*** *dead.*

Comment: The subject of "plays" is "One".  Although it's closer to the verb, "meanies" is merely the object of the preposition "of".

Answer (score 1):

**plays**.
It doesn't really matter if **meanies** is plural, it will always be with an *s*, as in the following examples:

> Every time one of you *losers* **trys** to leave the prison, you should just picture this guy coming at you!

> Whenever one of you *children* **wants** to go the market, just let me know.